# PHP no recibe parametros despues de submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, formularios, plugin

Estoy haciendo una formulario relativamente sencillo en el que uso el plugin `multiple-select`.
Este es el formulario:

```
<form id="frmDatos" class="form-horizontal" action="txartelak.php" method="post">



    <input type="submit"  class="btn" id="salida" name="salida" value="<?php echo $lang["BUSCAR"] ?>" onclick="alert('Pulsado')">    
    <a href="listados.php" class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $lang["VOLVER"]?></a>
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">                    
                <!-- Año escolar -->
                <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 control-label" for="annoMostrar"><?php //echo $lang["AÑOACADEMICO"] ?></label>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">                    
                    <input id="annoMostrar" maxlength="4" name="annoMostrar" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php //echo $annoMostrar ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                    <input id="annoSig" maxlength="4" name="annoSig" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>            
                <!-- Falta añadir multiselect de alumnos y etapa -->
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 control-label" for="annoMostrar"><?php echo "ALUMNO"//$lang["AÑOACADEMICO"] ?></label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-6" style="padding-top:10px;">        
                    
                    <select id="alumnos" style="width:100%" id="alumnos" name="alumnos[]" class="js-example-basic-single" multiple="multiple" style="height: 30px" >                        
                        <?php foreach ($filtroUsuarios as $monitores) { ?>
                            <option  value="<?php echo $monitores["USCOD"]; ?>" ><?php echo $monitores["USCOD"]."-".$monitores["SNOM"]; ?></option>                        
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
            
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 control-label" for="annoMostrar"><?php echo "ETAPA"//$lang["AÑOACADEMICO"] ?></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6" style="padding-top:10px;">        
                    <select id="etapas" style="width:100%" id="etapas" name="etapas[]" class="js-example-basic-single" multiple="multiple" style="height: 30px">                        
                        <?php foreach ($filtroEtapas as $monitores) { ?>
                            <option  value="<?php echo $monitores["ETCOD"]; ?>"><?php echo $monitores["ETCOD"]."-".$monitores["ETDESCE"]; ?></option>                        
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2" >
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 control-label" for="annoMostrar"><?php echo "CURSO"//$lang["AÑOACADEMICO"] ?></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6" style="padding-top:10px;">        
                    <select id="cursos" style="width:100%" id="cursos" name="cursos[]" class="js-example-basic-single" multiple="multiple" style="height: 30px">                        
                        <?php foreach ($filtroClase as $monitores) { ?>
                            <option  value="<?php echo $monitores["SCLASE"]; ?>"><?php echo $monitores["SCLASE"]?></option>                        
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 control-label" for="annoMostrar"><?php echo "CLASE"//$lang["AÑOACADEMICO"] ?></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6" style="padding-top:10px;">        
                    <select id="clases" style="width:100%" id="clases" name="clases[]" class="js-example-basic-single" multiple="multiple" style="height: 30px">                        
                        <?php foreach ($filtroGrupo as $monitores) { ?>
                            <option  value="<?php echo $monitores["SGRUPO"]; ?>"><?php echo $monitores["SGRUPO"]?></option>                        
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-right">                                
                </div>                
            </div>
        
    </div>
    
</form>
```

El problema es el siguiente, los selects

```
            <select id="etapas" style="width:100%" id="etapas" name="etapas[]" class="js-example-basic-single" multiple="multiple" style="height: 30px">                        
                <?php foreach ($filtroEtapas as $monitores) { ?>
                    <option  value="<?php echo $monitores["ETCOD"]; ?>"><?php echo $monitores["ETCOD"]."-".$monitores["ETDESCE"]; ?></option>                        
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
```

Los cargo con una consulta que he realizado previamente, esto se cargan correctamente, a continuacion les implemento el plugin.

```
$("#alumnos").multipleSelect({
    filter: true,
    multiple: true                    
});
$('#alumnos').multipleSelect('checkAll');
```

Esto funciona sin problemas y no me da ningun tipo de error, ni de javascript,jquery o PHP.

Ahora bien, a la hora de pulsar el submit, dependiendo directamente del lugar del formulario donde se encuentra funciona o no.

Esto es porque no se definen los indices despues del primer select. Para comprobar esto lo he hecho de la siguiente manera.

```
if(isset($_POST['salida'])){
    echo $_POST['salida'];
    $alumnos = $_POST['alumnos'];
    for($i==0;$i<count ($alumnos);$i++){
        echo $alumnos[$i];
    }
    $etapas = $_POST['etapas'];
    for($i==0;$i<count ($etapas);$i++){
        echo $etapas[$i];
    }
    $cursos = $_POST['cursos'];
    for($i==0;$i<count ($cursos);$i++){
        echo $cursos[$i];
    }
    $clases = $_POST['clases'];
    for($i==0;$i<count ($clases);$i++){
        echo $clases[$i];
    }
}
```

Esto me devuelve por pantalla lo siguiente

> Buscar
>
> "El codigo de los alumnos seleccionados"
>
> Notice: Undefined index: etapas in /var/www/html/txartelak.php on line 262
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cursos in /var/www/html/txartelak.php on line 266
>
> Notice: Undefined index: clases in /var/www/html/txartelak.php on line 270

Si situó el input después del primer select, el formulario no se envía porque tampoco se define este indice.
El problema parece ser del plugin, pero ya lo he usado en otro formulario y no me ha dado ningun problema.

Por lo tanto veo dos posibles soluciones a las que espero que alguien pueda dar la respuesta.

1. Es un código largo y tedioso de entender por lo podría tener un fallo que no he visto.
2. La posibilidad de usar otro plugin que tenga la misma característica de seleccionar todos por medio de un checkbox, que no de problemas con PHP.

### EDICION

He hecho unas pocas pruebas mas y me he dado cuenta que esto pasa cuando selecciono gran cantidad de opciones en el select. El fallo se donde esta, cual es y la razón me falta saber como solucionarlo.

### EDICION 2

A partir de la primera edición, de saber que el error dependia directamente del numero de resultados, he probado cual es el total de selecciones que hay que hacer para que ocurra el error, este error salta exactamente cuando seleccionas 1000 checkbox.

Comment: cuales son eseas lineas que mensiona ?

Comment: @CriticalGhost menciono muchas lineas de codigo, aclarame donde tienes dudas

Comment: *Notice: Undefined index: etapas in /var/www/html/txartelak.php on line 262

Notice: Undefined index: cursos in /var/www/html/txartelak.php on line 266

Notice: Undefined index: clases in /var/www/html/txartelak.php on line 270*

Comment: esas @Andoni Alda

Comment: Esas lineas aparecen al usar el bloque de codigo justo en la parte superior donde las menciono. Al hacer `echo` me muestra por pantalla el resultado. Como son `arrays` de datos lo muestro con un `for`

Comment: Bueno, no se entiende bien el asunto y analizar tu código y tratar de entender lo que quieres hacer es algo complicado. Además, sabiendo que más adelante, por experiencia propia, terminarás prescindiendo del plugin y lo harás tú mismo. Ya que no es tan difícil hacerlo uno mismo. Quizá para aclarar la cosa: **el error es que estás intentando postear algo y no lo recuperas**. Aquí:  `if(isset($_POST['salida'])){`  los otros `$_POST` que tienes deberían ser enviados pero no lo son, eso es lo que dice el mensaje de error. ¿Puedes indicar dónde haces y cómo construyes el `$_POST`?

Comment: En los bucles for tienes un doble igual "==" de comparación, en lugar de "=" de asignación de valor.

Comment: @Carmen, ya me habia dado cuenta, un pequeño fallo pero el problema sigue siendo el mismo.

Comment: @A.Cedano el `$_POST` no lo construyo de ninguna manera en especial. Cuando creo el formulario digo que lo haga con el metodo post y que se llame a si mismo. Entonces cuando ejecuto el submit el entra por `if(isset($_POST['salida'])){` y me muestra el error. Hasta ahora he hecho los formularios asi y sin ningun problema. Pero este me da errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano si que podria hacer el plugin por mi mismo y se que no es dificil, que cualquiera con un conocimiento medio javascript html y css podria hacerlo. Pero eso requiere un tiempo y la posibilidad de que me salga mal, o no cumpla con las expectativas o tener otros tantos problemas.

Comment: Creo que el error puede deberse a que llamas a tus select con esto al final `[]` Ejemplo: `name="etapas[]"` , entonces el `$_POST` no los encuentra. Creo que debes llamarlos: `name="etapas"...`, lo mismo para los otros.

Comment: @A.Cedano esto no es asi, al ser selects multiples si el valor lo pongo sin `[]` me daria un error cuando lo recojo porque no lo interpreta como un array. De hecho si seleccionas menos de 1000 elementos en el select, no da ningun problema.

Comment: Entonces puede que le falte el atributo `multiple`a tus select. Ejemplo: `<select multiple id="etapas" style="width:100%" id="etapas" name="etapas[]" class="js-example-basic-single" multiple="multiple" style="height: 30px">`, por cierto, tienes **dos veces el atributo id**, ponlo una sola vez, pues podría darte problemas.

Comment: ¡1.000 elementos seleccionados en el select! Casi te diría que debes plantearte una estrategia diferente de diseño. ¿Cómo selecciona 1.000 elementos el usuario?

Comment: Hola mira ver que valor te esta devolviendo las variables **$etapas, $cursos y $clases**. el resultado tiene que ser un **array**  eso lo puedes hacer con el comando de **php** **print_r**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Respuesta larga:

Probé tu código en local y a mí me fallaba a partir de 2.500 elementos seleccionados. Eso me llevó a pensar que el problema podría ser más de configuración del navegador o del servidor (servidor web o PHP) que un problema con el código.

Entonces probé en local con Chrome, Firefox e Internet Explorer y me encontré con que todos ellos fallaban a partir del mismo número de elementos seleccionados (2500). Con eso descarté que fuera un error del navegador y me centré en la configuración del servidor.

Entonces abrí la configuración de PHP (en el fichero `php.ini`) y me encontré que está esta fila:

```
; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
max_input_vars = 2500
```

Es decir, el máximo número de variables que se le pueden pasar en GET, POST o con una cookie es 2500. ¡El número que me da dallo! Incrementé ese número a 250000 y ya me funciona.

Haciendo algo de investigación online, parece que el valor por defecto de esa variable en PHP <=5.3 es 1000 (que coincidiría con el valor que recibes) y en PHP >=5.4 es 2500 (que coincidiría con el valor que recibo).

Si sigues recibiendo errores, eso se podría deber a que estás alcanzando los límites en otros puntos. Hay otras variables que controlan el tamaño que se puede enviar en el POST (`post_max_size`), intenta incrementando su valor para ver si te funciona.

### tl;dr;

Incrementa el número de variables que puedes pasar por GET/POST/COOKIE porque ese es seguramente el motivo. Lo puedes hacer en `php.ini` cambiando el valor de `max_input_vars`:

```
; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
max_input_vars = 250000
```

Comment: Suponia que tendria que ser algo asi, muchas gracias.

Comment: @AndoniAlda ¿te funcionó esta solución?

Comment: Si, se me habia olvidado aceptarla, perdon.